# What are the (dis)advantages of Pimcore?

Tags: zend-framework, content-management-system, pimcore

I am looking for a CMS based on Zend Framework and I read about Pimcore. Now I have some questions about it:

- Does anyone have experience with this CMS?
- What are the (dis)advantages?
- How is the learning curve? (I work a lot with ZF)
- Can you develop a new module?

Comment: post was useful to me.was looking at tomatoCMS actually and never heard of pimcore.So have you tried it anyway? if so how do you find it?.thanks

Comment: I worked with TomatoCMS, but the development of it dropped dead it seems ... Therefor I started looking into other options. The only other option I discovered was PimCore (there a others, but really bad or old ones). PimCore was ok, but they work with pages in a strange way. Their way of work didn't fit into mine. Therefor I didn't adapt it for my projects. Together with Eddie, I'm working on this project: https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pimcore rocks as an advanced enterprise cms, ams, pims, what have you.  We have been using it in a corporate environment as our asset management system since v1.2 and are using v1.4.1 right now and loving it.

General Disadvantages (when compared to the run of the mill popular cms's like joomla/drupal/wordpress etc):

1. Steeper development learning curve, need to know zend framework and extjs if you want to modify the admin area or add plugins (although i consider most of the older cms's to be a nightmare to develop on).
2. Advanced admin UI, Not end user friendly for standard cms tasks like adding a page.  Not immediately clear how to add a page, add to custom navigations, etc.
3. Coder required to get it setup and really use it to its potential.
4. Backend plugin work requires both front-end/extjs/ajax knowledge and backend/php/xend framework/mysql knowledge.
5. Runs best on a dedicated machine, needs lots of processing and power for the zend framework to be fast and putting on shared hosting requires some tweaking to get working.
6. Still early product so some things like branding the admin and other minor stuff is not that flexible yet.  Not everything is completely easily modifiable without touching the core yet.
7. Not a ton of themes or add-ons yet.
8. A little tough to contribute, can't just fork it on github etc.
9. No front end login/registration/members area module, you need to code it yourself if you need front end user authentication as of present.

Advantages:

1. From an architectural standpoint it is super powerful and extensible and can do anything with it since it is completely based on an object/asset/document model with an API to use those objects and a plugin architecture to customize the admin.  This is a great model for a catalog of items, which most cms's revolve around but not limiting in any way.
2. Coding is pleasant using the Pimcore API and Zend Framework/ExtJS and fairly bug free for major features.
3. Lots of built in features out of the box that enterprise systems need like users/groups/permissions, versions, scheduling, cacheing, cdn, and i18n internationalization.
4. Lots of wow factor user interface stuff in the admin using ExtJS framework like drag and drop, grids, editing objects.
5. Modern website editing features/flexibility with in place editing, drag and drop/reorder content, content blocks, snippets and so on.
6. Not very many roadblocks or limiting factors, basically it's open to anything you want to do and rarely do you run into something that is a complete road block requiring editing core files.
7. Most use cases are covered and flexible enough to allow improvements and customization without being a nightmare.
8. Built in upgrading mechanism.
9. Plugin architecture.
10. PHP Unit testing plugin.
11. Built in admin UI for creating extensible classes and objects.
12. Admin UI for laying out the screens that allow editing object data using many preconfigured ui controls like textboxes, sliders, checkboxes, etc.

Even though Pimcore in early phases it is an excellent enterprise cms framework and will handle any task but be prepared to dive into code figure out stuff as you go.  I'm sure this will change as it matures and they make it easier for people to contribute code and open up a marketplace for addons.  Currently I wouldn't say it's a replacement for regular websites using wordpress or drupal with tons of themes and addons and end user UI fanciness for normal website cms operations.  But since you are a coder and don't mind writing your addons using extjs and zend then it's well worth the flexibility in my mind.  My recommendation right now is to go with concrete5 if you want a modern Zend MVC CMS website replacement that is easy to use but still pleasant to develop on.  Over time pimcore will give all cms's a run for their money though due to it's awesome architecture.

Hope that helps!

Comment: 8. A little tough to contribute, can't just fork it on github etc.-> is outdated, they're on github also now: http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/2011/11/01/We%27re+on+GitHub%21

Comment: Could let me know how you manage team development? Since object are generated on db and files as well I dont know how to approach the development when I have 4 people on the project ... We use svn for other projects. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah we never quite nailed that down.  In fact I would add to my original post that a downside is that data is stored in both the db and filesystem.  We ran into bottlenecks both from a development/deployment and performance standpoint since every admin action and plugin required modifying filesystem and database.

Answer (score 4):

Now its already version 1.4.4.

I am using it for some time, for all my web projects. 
It is really an excellent core for developing various projects.

I think that the biggest advantage is that there is no frontend module. You just make custum one. And I had no problems so far updateing the pimcore, becase you only update backend, and really nothing can go wrong if you havent changed core. Maybe some miner updates on frontend are needed but i had no such exemple for now.

Other advanategs:
- plugin development is nice arhitectured, and you can use extjs for almost any purpose. Since version 1.4.3. you can also put your views and controllers in plugin, so you dont have to code like login and other stuff more than once.
- WebDav for Assets managment
- pixlr for image editing
- very good page and subpage editing (you actualy see page how it looks while editing), you can develop custom elements of page easily
- community and pimcore team is very helpful on forum
- ...

Disadvantages:
- people that are not really in to computers find it difficult to edit simple page, people that like to explore a bit and are not afraid to click and try fond it interesting (you have to learn custumer in beginning)

For me its very inutiutive, but I am a programmer.

If you have Zend Framework background I think its very good choice. After a year of usege on my projects I am very satisfied that I decided to use and learn Pimcore.

Answer (score 1):

I think, pimcore is a very good solution for someone with zf-experience. Good documentation, good community, small learning curve.

One disadvantage: there is no frontend because you have to write your own controllers and views. But this can be a big advantage if you hate customizing frontends (like typo3 with all the css you have to customize).

Answer (score 1):

****Advnatages of Pimcore****

1. Pimcore is fully open-source and based on leading Symfony, the leading PHP framework. It has a well-developed partner network and community support.
2. In contrast to other systems that have quite rigid architecture Pimcore is designed as a platform for developers.
3. It can be used to model complex data architecture with ease and develop features tailored to customer needs.
4. It provides a fully integrated platform for Product Information Management, Digital Asset Management, and Enterprise Content Management. This ensures there is no duplication of assets and content and data across multiple systems.
5. All PIM features are also available through a REST-based Web Service allowing easy integration with other applications.

**Disadvantages of Pimcore**

1. Pimcore is not intended to be used as an out-of-the-box system but as a platform. Hence non-technical users take some time to get started with it.
2. Small community. Without a robust community, you may not have the support you need that other platforms can offer when you’re starting out.
3. Lack of plugins. The platform’s built-in collection of plugins isn’t diverse. Plus, the lack of support from the community means there are few plugins added. Thus, you might have to make your own if you need to extend its functionality.
4. Set up and maintenance needs technical expertise. With not enough plugins available and the lack of community support, you might have to do a lot of manual programming to develop the platform you want.
5. It's not very easy to use. If you want to learn the basics of Pimcore, I recommend starting [here](https://factory.hr/blog/learning-pimcore-with-practical-examples-for-beginners).