# Pimcore Vs PyroCMS

Tags: software-design, pyrocms, pimcore

Going forward a company I'm working with atm would like to stop with various frameworks/cms systems and go forward with just one for all future clients.

To that end, I've prepped a list of options and it's been whittled down to Pimcore and PyroCMS.
I'm a CI developer so clearly Pyro wins for me, but the guys who will be developing custom modules are more comfy in Zend. I found this: [What are the (dis)advantages of pimcore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767769/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-pimcore) and found it quite enlightening.

So I'm curious to know thoughts on the two systems based on the following criteria:

1. Reskinning potential (front end themes etc).
2. Custom module ease. Building modules is really easy in Pyro and intuitive (if you know CI).. is Pimcore as easy for a Zend guru? Also, just buying/downloading existing modules, which is more prolific?
3. Multi site usage (can one install allow an admin user from site A to only see site A content?)

The docs and marketing blurb is great for both sites, but any hands on experience here would be useful.

I'm thinking that we could also just use the Zend library within Pyro (as you can do with CI on its own). Anyone reckon that'll be a headache to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyroCMS developer dropping by.

PyroCMS can handle all of the 3 requirements you have requested. Now, CI and Zend users often have arguments over which framework is better, who is the best, bla bla bla, but it can easily be said that CI is the easiest to learn.

If you have some Zend developers, while they might prefer to use a Zend-based CMS that really should not be a selling point on the application itself. These days people put so much focus on which framework they prefer they seem to ignore everything else.

So, evaluate the two products on their own merits.

PyroCMS can handle multi-site and the frontend (and backend!) can easily be reskinned using just HTML and some basic tags - much like Smarty-ish.

And yes, you can use Zend components in your CodeIgniter/PyroCMS application, so that shouldn't be something to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

We have used Zend in a few of our custom PyroCMS modules. Definitely go with PyroCMS so you get the flexibility of both frameworks if you desire. PyroCMS 2.1 just came out and it just keeps getting better.